# Why do I get dizzy when I expect an user interface to scroll while it's lagging?

Tags: computers, dizziness, motion-sickness

I have a lot of programs running on my laptop. I got very used to scrolling things with my two fingers on a touchpad. The problem is when the programs start to lag and my eyes expect the scroll, but the scroll isn't there. It causes a lot of eye strain and a headache and a frustrating feeling. My eyes keep expecting the scroll and they move slightly and they feel like they're going to explode.

Why is that? I'm usually motion sick while watching a screen while in a braking vehicle and I get a bad feeling in my stomach. But I'm not in a vehicle, but sitting still.